# Time.toMillis(false) of 1/1/1941 always returns -1 if timezone is Pacific/Tongatapu in Android

Tags: android, time, timezone

When I test below code, t1 is -1.

```
Time t = new Time();
t.clear("Pacific/Tongatapu");
t.set(1, Calendar.JANUARY, 1941);
t.normalize(false);
Log.d("ss", "[onCreate] t1= " + t.toMillis(false));
```

then I test below code t2 is -915109200.

```
Time t = new Time();
t.clear("Pacific/Tongatapu");
t.set(2, Calendar.JANUARY, 1941);
t.normalize(false);
Log.d("ss", "[onCreate] t2= " + t.toMillis(false));
```

I found that from 1941/01/01T00:00:00 to 1941/01/01T00:40:00, Time.toMillis() returns -1 if timezone is "Pacific/Tongatapu".

Please help me to understand this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [timezone change](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=277&syear=1925) on Wednesday, 1 January 1941, 00:40:00, which explains the returned value.